# syntax error near unexpected token `fi' | Format Appears Correct

Tags: bash, if-statement, terminal, centos, syntax-error

I'm trying to execute this script from the terminal (via `sh PreStartupCommands.sh`) and I get the following error in my terminal window:

```
/home/MinecraftServers/Ephona/serverconfig/PreStartupCommands.sh: line 14: syntax error near unexpected token `fi'
/home/MinecraftServers/Ephona/serverconfig/PreStartupCommands.sh: line 14: `fi'
```

---

**PreStartupCommands.sh**

```
#!/bin/bash
############################################
########### PreStartupCommands #############
############################################
#
### Update Ephona_sky ###
if [ -f '/home/MinecraftServers/Ephona/Ephona_sky_edit/lock.txt' ] ; then
    echo "Lock exists"
else
    echo "Lock Does Not Exist"
    echo "Copying World ..."
    echo "World Copied"
    echo "Creating Lock"
fi
```

---

Everything appears fine to me.

- The spacing around the [ and ] exists
- The `if`, `then`, `else`, `fi` tags are all included
- All quotations are opened and closed
- Spelling is correct...

Comment: Make sure you don't have any funny "whitespace" in the file.

Comment: Works for me also. I tested both branches.

Comment: Try copying this script back into your text editor from StackOverflow and see if you can reproduce it.

Comment: You input file seems to have CR+LF line endings.  Use `dos2unix` or something else to remove the line feeds.

Comment: Copied and pasted it directly form here, same result. I also tested it on my OTHER computer running on Ubuntu, and it has the same result.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Update**: The issue turned out to be that the script file had Windows-style line endings (`\r\n`) rather than what `bash` - and Unix utilities in general - expect (`\n` only), as @devnull suspected.

---

Normally, `sh` is symlinked to `bash` on CentOS, so your script SHOULD work fine.

(As an aside: any POSIX-compliant shell should work with the specific sample script in your question, however.
General caveat: As @Scrutinizer points out in a comment, invoking `bash` as `sh` implies subtle changes in behavior - see http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Bash-POSIX-Mode.html (*) - though bashisms still work).

Generally, however, if you're invoking a `bash` script, it's both conceptually clearer and safer to invoke it with `bash` - given that `sh` could have been redefined to invoke a different shell.

Of course, you can run `chmod +x PreStartupCommands.sh` to make your script executable by itself, which makes the problem go away (assuming the problem is related to what executable is processing the script).

<sup>(*) Invoking `bash` as `sh` on **OSX** has *additional* implications (since `sh` is a separately compiled *executable* rather than a symlink there), namely that shell option `xpg_echo` is turned ON by default, and that in the absence of `$FCEDIT`, `ed` is used (without checking for `$EDITOR`, as `bash` normally does).</sup>

Comment: Neither of those solutions worked. :/

Comment: Have you examined your script for `CR` instances, as @devnull suggests? Run `cat -v PreStartupCommands.sh` and if `^M` is contained in the output, you need to remove `CR` (`\r`) instances.

Comment: Yup. That was the issue. Darn Notepad++ >.>

Comment: It's a subtle issue; glad you were able to resolve it; perhaps `Notepad++` (which I'm not familiar with) can be configured to default to and/or can convert to Unix-style line endings (`\n` only, instead of Windows-style `\r\n`).

Comment: Also, even if `sh` is linked to `bash`, when using `sh`, `bash` gets invoked with the `--posix` option so the behavior is different..
See http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Bash-POSIX-Mode.html

Comment: @Scrutinizer Thanks for the hint and link. For _non-interactive non-login_ shells (as in this case), the differences in behavior are subtle (but noteworthy), and it's important to note that bashisms, such as `[[ ... ]]` and brace expansion, _still_ work when invoked as `sh`. Invoking as `sh` also _changes what startup files are read_, which mostly affects _interactive and/or login shells_. However, should you use `$BASH_ENV` to point to an initialization file for _non-interactive_ shells (rare), running as `sh` will ignore that, too.